# Trouble Building Messages: Invalid Declaration 'float32'

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to define a simple message for a larger suite of messages that just defines the limits of some attribute by containing a maximum and a minimum value. So I defined the following message as Limits.msg:

```
float32 minimum
float32 maximum
```

The CMakeLists.txt is very simple right now while I debug this issue:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
    std_msgs
    message_generation
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  Limits.msg
  GPSFix.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
  std_msgs
)
```

I'm keeping GPSFix.msg in there because it's another simple message that builds just fine for some reason. In any case, if I catkin_make from the catkin workspace, I get this:

```
ava@3b97b310abf0:~/workspace/test_msgs$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs
Source space: /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/src
Build space: /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/build
Devel space: /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/devel
Install space: /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/ava/workspace/sci288ava/devel;/home/ava/workspace/ava_ros/devel;/home/ava/workspace/ros_ivp/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic;/home/ava/CMake/Modules/
-- This workspace overlays: /home/ava/workspace/sci288ava/devel;/home/ava/workspace/ava_ros/devel;/home/ava/workspace/ros_ivp/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - test_msgs
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'test_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(test_msgs/test_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em:56: error: <class 'genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec'>: /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/src/test_msgs/test_msgs/msg/Limits.msg: Invalid declaration: float32 minimum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3302, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3300, in main
    invoke(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3283, in invoke
    interpreter.wrap(interpreter.file, (file, name))
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2295, in wrap
    self.fail(e)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2284, in wrap
    callable(*args)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2359, in file
    self.safe(scanner, done, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2401, in safe
    self.parse(scanner, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2421, in parse
    token.run(self, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 1425, in run
    interpreter.execute(self.code, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2595, in execute
    _exec(statements, self.globals, locals)
  File "/usr/bin/empy", line 42, in _exec
    exec("""exec code in globals""")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/deps.py", line 45, in find_msg_dependencies_with_type
    spec = genmsg.msg_loader.load_msg_from_file(msg_context, msg_file, full_type_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 289, in load_msg_from_file
    raise InvalidMsgSpec('%s: %s'%(file_path, e))
genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec: /home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/src/test_msgs/test_msgs/msg/Limits.msg: Invalid declaration: float32  minimum
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  
  execute_process(/home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/usr/bin/python" "/usr/bin/empy" "--raw-errors" "-F"
  "/home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/build/test_msgs/test_msgs/cmake/test_msgs-genmsg-context.py"
  "-o"
  "/home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/build/test_msgs/test_msgs/cmake/test_msgs-genmsg.cmake"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em") returned error
  code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:303 (em_expand)
  test_msgs/test_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:16 (generate_messages)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ava/workspace/test_msgs/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

This looks like it's telling me that float32 is not a valid type for a message entry, but it's one of the standard variable types. Also, I tried changing it to uint8, which is used in GPSFix.msg, and it still throws the same error. I'm kind of at a loss here - does anyone see something I'm missing?

Basic Information:

- Version: ROS kinetic
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS running in a Docker container on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux system
- Compiling with gcc v5.4.0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329686/trouble-building-messages:-invalid-declaration-%27float32%27/) by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2019-07-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently the problem was that I used tabs in my msg file rather than spaces; as soon as I replaced the tabs, it compiled just fine. I don't understand why this would be an issue, but for anyone else who might run into this, it's something to try.

---

Originally posted by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) with karma: 320 on 2019-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [j.clownz](https://answers.ros.org/users/45405/j.clownz/) on 2020-01-31**:
It solved my problem too. Thanks.

I also wonder why this would be a problem.

**Comment by [gbohus](https://answers.ros.org/users/58051/gbohus/) on 2020-09-01**:
Crazy, but true, thank you 8). I also noticed that the first whitespace after the type has to be space, after which you can use tabs.